# How can I install windows after I installed ubuntu, in the same partition?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, bios

The problem I'm having is that when I install windows on the same partition as ubuntu, my system will only mark windows as bootable and I'll lose access to grub.

How can I install both systems on the same partition having grub as the first boot?

Comment: It seems that you want something else. Please ask about the real problem. See [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2):

You can't install Windows to the same partition with Ubuntu.